# function with struct parameter and its inside objects

Tags: c, pointers, struct, member, unions

I searched with my problem but with no success

I do not know how to implement proper function `iphost()`.

Well I have file library.h file in which I store variables and function `iphost()`.

There is another file called `main.c` where I run function `iphost(...)`.

I really do not know how to fix my problem.

I got error `adr_srvr` doesn't have element `sin_addr`.

```
/home/user/Desktop/pap_lab2/2/biblioteka.h|23|error: request for member ‘sin_addr’ in something not a structure or union|
```

Probably I  **declared wrong arguments with that stars pointers and ampersands**. Can anybody help me?

```
library.h
```

```
void iphost(char* arg,struct sockaddr_in *adr_srvr)
{
    if(*arg>=(char)'0' && *arg<=(char)'9')
    {
        printf("Prawdopodobnie wprowadzono IP: %s\n", arg);
        inet_aton(arg, &adr_srvr.sin_addr);//here ERROR
        srvr_addr = inet_ntoa(adr_srvr.sin_addr);
    }
}
```

```
main.c
```

```
iphost(argv[2], &adr_srvr); // OK ?
```

Little help to undestand the code:
I cannot get to adr_srvr.sin_addr.
char* arg is arguments inputing by me, 4example: "127.0.0.1".
adr_srvr.sin_addr store this 127.0.0.1
srvr_addr is char*

The normal code which works okay is (without functon) in main.c :

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  int z;
  int x;
  char *srvr_addr;
  struct sockaddr_in adr_srvr;
  struct sockaddr_in adr;
  struct hostent *he;
  int len_inet;
  int s;
    char dgram[512];
    struct in_addr **addr_list;
    char buf[512];

    //USTAWIENIE POLACZENIA
    //CZY WPISANO IP

    if(argv[1][0]>=(char)'0' && argv[1][0]<=(char)'9')
    {
        printf("Prawdopodobnie wprowadzono IP: %s\n", argv[1]);
        inet_aton(argv[1], &adr_srvr.sin_addr);
        srvr_addr = inet_ntoa(adr_srvr.sin_addr);
    } else {}

...
}
```

### ---------

I have similar question so I edit here. How can I implement this in function?:

```
else
    {
         if ((he = gethostbyname(arg)) == NULL) {  // get the host info
            herror("gethostbyname");
            return 2;
        }

        // print information about this host:
        printf("Wykryty HOST: '%s' ", arg);
        printf("zamieniam na IP: ");
        addr_list = (struct in_addr **)he->h_addr_list;
        printf("%s", srvr_addr = inet_ntoa(*addr_list[0]));
        printf("\n");

    }
```

Comment: Try `inet_aton (arg, &(adr_srvr->sin_addr));`
`srvr_addr = inet_ntoa(adr_srvr->sin_addr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adr_srvr` is a pointer. To access its fields, you need to use `adr_srvr->sin_addr` instead of `adr_srvr.sin_addr`.

In general, use `a.field` when `a` is a struct, and `a->field` when `a` is a pointer to a struct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this most certainly *is* a problem:

```
inet_aton(arg, &adr_srvr.sin_addr);
```

Because your function signature is:

```
void iphost (char* arg, struct sockaddr_in *adr_srvr)
//                                         ^
//                                         |
//                                         +- see here
```

this means that `adr_srvr` is a *pointer* rather than a structure.

You should be using:

```
inet_aton (arg, &(adr_srvr->sin_addr));
srvr_addr = inet_ntoa (adr_srvr->sin_addr);
```

Comment: thanks for a help @paxdiablo @Sylvain @interjay but after changing point to arrow i got defferencing pointer of incomplete type. Should i think that it can be casue due declaring in my library.h at the beginning: struct struct sockaddr_in adr_srvr; ?

Comment: edit: it works :) i included libraries by @adirau in my library instead main. I really dont know why...

Comment: edit2: okay i know, my library was first included. Thanks guys :)

Comment: I have similar question. In function you wrote above there is struct sockaddr_in *adr_srvr. How can i save something to adr_srvr.sin_port ? I tried sthing like this &(adr_srvr->sin_port) = htons(xxx) but i know this is wrong. Thanks in advance. Where can i read about doing something like that? Probably i should write: adr_srvr->sin_port = htons(xxx) but after this i cannot send message. I think that cause this adr_srvr ...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
```

- thats where the sockaddr_in structure definition resides

for the inet_aton signature:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

Comment: @Michal Mokrzycki:: You meant included?

Answer (score 1):

You have a pointer to a `struct sockaddr_in`, so you have to dereference it. Change your code to the following:

```
void iphost(char* arg,struct sockaddr_in *adr_srvr)
{
    if(*arg>=(char)'0' && *arg<=(char)'9')
    {
        printf("Prawdopodobnie wprowadzono IP: %s\n", arg);
        inet_aton(arg, &(adr_srvr->sin_addr));
        srvr_addr = inet_ntoa(adr_srvr->sin_addr);
    }
}
```